# How to fix Cloudant-client connection error

Tags: cloudant

I used cloudant-client-1.0.0.jar to make a test to check the connection to cloudant server as:

```
import com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient;
import com.cloudant.client.api.Database;

public class test {

    private CloudantClient client=null;


    public CloudantClient connect(){
        client=new CloudantClient("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        System.out.println("Connection successful! "+client.getBaseUri());

        return client;
    }

    public Database getDb(String dbName){

        Database db=connect().database(dbName, true);
        System.out.println("Datase avaible - "+db.getDBUri());

        return db;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new test().getDb("_user");

    } 
}
```

However, the system shows errors:

Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
    at connection.test.connect(test.java:13)
    at connection.test.getDb(test.java:21)
    at connection.test.main(test.java:30)
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're  missing a dependency for the library, Apache http client. However you should use Maven, gradle or a similar build tool which understands Maven repositories. You should also look at upgrading to 2.4.1, it contains numerous improvements and bug fixes.